# css resources have a type text/html how to fix?

Tags: html, css, mime-types

Here is the url: [now hidden]

If you click "login" at the top right, there is a popup which you will notice has no css. However if you load the source of the iframe and look at the network tab the css files have a type of text/html. How do I fix this? Is this an IIS setting?

Use this url: [now hidden] for testing.

This is a url on our production site that works! [now hidden]

*** Edit ***
Sorry I have to hide the URL's

Comment: The popup contains an iframe w/ a Chrome `Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Unknown` message for me.

Comment: How are you serving the css? is it from a static file on your server? Or is it generated by some server side code?

Comment: Its a static file on the server and css extensions resolve to the mime type "text/css" as you can see from the rest of the site. It just doesn't seem to work under the self signed certificate.

Comment: It looks like you got it working just now, there was some javascript in the CSS files..

Answer (score 0):

Solved it was a web.config issue where the themes folder was not marked as "ignore SSL"